# How to have a function that works both for entering and clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this input and a submit button as :

```
<input onKeyDown={handleEnter} value={inputValue} onChange={(nv) => setInputValue(nv.currentTarget.value)} /> <button onClick={handleClick}>Submit</button>
```

which triggers a function :

```
  const handleEnter = (e) => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      handleSubmit()
    }
  }
```

However now I have to define another separate function for `onClick` to handle the button. This seems to be a case of *DRY* (don't repeat yourself) and I wish to know how I can handle the value with both clicking the button and pressing enter using the same function.

Comment: Why not using the [onSubmit](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) event instead?

Comment: If using a form why do you need to listen to onclick of the button? Also note that a single input in a form will submit when enter key pressed while input focused also making the onKeydown redundant

Comment: Note what you are probably looking for is checking `e.type` which would be either `"click"` or `"keydown"`

Answer (score 0):

It isn't repeating yourself to pass `handleSubmit` as the click event handler, and to create a seperate function which tests what key was pressed and then calls `handleSubmit`.

All the logic which is "the same" is wrapped up in the `handleSubmit` function.

---

That said, you should probably wrap the form controls in a `<form>` and *just* use its `submit` event. (Note you'll want to call `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: I am not using form. I just get the value through updating the input and then use it. I was wondering if there is anything in the EVENT that would indicate a click on a button which I could use as a logic to handle the submit.